# Extract the db key type from an entity, given the db key members

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Given an entity:

```
const someEntity = {
  id: 'someId',
  createdAt: 123234223453,
  name: 'Dudemanson',
}
```

And it's db key members:

```
const keyMembers = {
  hash: 'id',
  range: 'createdAt',
}
```

I wanna extract the database key:

```
const extractedDbKey = {
  id: 'someId',
  createdAt: 123234223453,
}
```

Here's my failing attempt:

```
type KeyFields<Entity extends object> = { hash: keyof Entity, range?: keyof Entity };

function toKey<Entity extends object, TheKeyFields extends KeyFields<Entity>>
(entity: Entity, keyFields: TheKeyFields): Pick<Entity, TheKeyFields[keyof TheKeyFields]> {
  const ret = {} as Pick<Entity, TheKeyFields[keyof TheKeyFields]>;
  (Object.keys(keyFields) as Array<keyof TheKeyFields>)
    .map((k) => keyFields[k]).forEach(k => ret[k] = entity[k]);
  return ret;
}
```

Some pointers please?

[Here's a playground](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/C4TwDgpgBA0hIDECWEA2ATAzgHgKIDtglQoIAPYCfLKAewCMArCAY2AD4oBeKAbygAWAQ0wCAXFADW8WgDMoBIqAA0UAE5D8AcwgB+CdJByFhYiCgBfANwAoG7ICu+Nklr4owWnBB5TJcpTUmHRMrMCqACoCEN7IaDQBVDSxKBg4imbs7DYAFFRKIBIZKlLwcWkSUTFlqVgAlBIACkgskr4FkdEp8ZgA2obGVd1pALqcvDZQUCxumMDqEPM8vBZQIlDNre1mndWItX0D8kM1PWO2UzkA8qFsAHSGmDmG5fVrwQCCaho+R1An+x67DqkymUDuAFshGAcs86txOC8Dv0RnU7rJaGpcEIWAJngiFsAUdxSH4QCi6hdCQ41O41ItbBYbEA)

Comment: Your playground is empty.  Is [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBBIFsCmBRMUCWUCeMC8MA3gFAxkwYAmAXDAOTzICSldANKecAE5ICGUJJQCCUWgEYATAGYZAFknyArNI7kYYPslp0AIgFdKSBH0jh2xAL7EcAByQwAyolTos2ACrZ7+GHaQgAGZwLmiYOADcxMSgkLAA1kjYALLGAEZI3BC+JOoAFnwQeTpUFurcpgDmSDo8-IIiUBaWMIUwsdARMAD03TAAPAC0gxpIQn4FUGwwINwwAG58ADb6SNkA7hhLSzAAVvrQMBlwUNwYYJU23g4A0kmpCBlZXj4E-kEwiSnpmRBRMeBDkgAB6nPjABq6NJ3XAEXLkKg6RhIFhlLi8ARCUQSGTyRTSOQqDjWK4+FCgioQoRQmEvBx4ThkAAKGGA8X6zmQYXcdOmMIeTwgdIA2l8Pvyfs9rgBdAB8UW6ACo-NcYOSwVTKDSknScoyKDQTmcLlF1HVMY1aGB9I9MlFLIrukA) what you want?

Comment: Are you asking for just the *type* of `extractedDbKey`?  Or are you looking to actually extract the *value* of it too?  The latter would involve a function as well as a type

Comment: Hey @jcalz, I'm building an ORM for dynamodb, so, `someEntity` and `keyMembers` are both dynamic inputs. When executing the query, I'm using those inputs to extract the entity key. So yeah, it's a function that extracts the entity key from the entity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're only interested in computing the output type from the input types, you will end up using a `Pick`.  First let's define the input types:

```
const someEntity = {
    id: 'someId',
    createdAt: 123234223453,
    name: 'Dudemanson',
}
type SomeEntityType = typeof someEntity;

const keyMembers = {
    hash: 'id',
    range: 'createdAt',
} as const; // <-- need that, or values will just be string
type KeyMembersType = typeof keyMembers;
```

Note that you need something like that [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/overview.html#const-assertions) to have the compiler remember that the property values of `keyMembers` are of [string literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#string-literal-types) like `"id"` and `"createdAt"` instead of the unhelpful `string`.

And the output type ends up using `Pick` on the object type `SomeEntityType` with the keys from the property *values* of `KeyMembersType`, like this:

```
type ExtractedDbKeyType =
    Pick<SomeEntityType, KeyMembersType[keyof KeyMembersType]>;
/* type ExtractedDbKeyType = {
    id: string;
    createdAt: number;
}*/
```

---

If you want to write a function signature that works like this, you can do it this way:

```
function extractKeys<T extends object, K extends Record<keyof K, keyof T>>(
    entity: T,
    keys: K
) {
    const ret = {} as Pick<T, K[keyof K]>;
    (Object.keys(keys) as Array<keyof K>).
        map((k) => keys[k]).forEach(k => ret[k] = entity[k]);

    // Without the following assertion you get an output type like 
    // 'Pick<{...},"..."|"..."">' instead of a more straightforward object type.
    return ret as any as (typeof ret extends infer O ? { [P in keyof O]: O[P] } : never);
}
```

The implementation is just an example; the important thing is that it takes values of type `T` and `K` (where `K` is constrained so its values are from `keyof T`) and returns a value of type `Pick<T, K[keyof K]>`.  There's a little wrinkle with that return type; if you just return `Pick<T, K[keyof K]>`, it tends to be displayed as just `Pick<BlahBlah, "x"|"y"|"z">` (at least in my IDE).  So at the end there I use a mapped conditional type to expand out the object type into a more straightforward object type.  Like this:

```
const extractedDbKey = extractKeys(someEntity, keyMembers);

/* TYPE WITH ASSERTION:
const extractedDbKey: {
    id: string;
    createdAt: number;
}  */

/* TYPE WITHOUT ASSERTION:
const extractedDbKey: Pick<{
    id: string;
    createdAt: number;
    name: string;
}, "id" | "createdAt"> */
```

You can see that the former type is nicer.  It's up to you whether that matters though.

Oh and the implementation is at least reasonable on your example:

```
console.log(extractedDbKey) // {id: "someId", createdAt: 123234223453}
```

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBBIFsCmBRMUCWUCeMC8MA3gFAxkwYAmAXDAOTzICSldANKecAE5ICGUJJQCCUWgEYATAGYZAFknyArNI7kYYPslp0AIgFdKSBH0jh2xAL7EcAByQwAyolTos2ACrZ7+GHaQgAGZwLmiYOADcxMSgkLAA1kjYALLGAEZI3BC+JOoAFnwQeTpUFurcpgDmSDo8-IIiUBaWMIUwsdARMAD03TAAPAC0gxpIQn4FUGwwINwwAG58ADb6SNkA7hhLSzAAVvrQMBlwUNwYYJU23g4A0kmpCBlZXj4E-kEwiSnpmRBRMeBDutTFAUAAPU58YANXRpO64Ai5chUHSMJAsMpcXgCISiCQyeSKaRyFQcaxXHzgyHQoSw+EvBx4ThkAAKGGA8X6zmQYXcDOm8IeTwgDIA2l8PoKfs9rgBdAB8UW6ACo-NcYFSKjTKHSkgycsyKDQTmcLlF1HUcY1aGB9I9MlFLMrutFAvowNCMOAYEgIVqoPCIP0PD6IUgwJRsiA0rskNCBaHBBHsgAlOOzSj9CXBG7TbMwDzy+UACkN4fC2FoHjU5C+EFoN2IAEoiIaOrBeLBES02myOcGBeKkpKFebyMWAPIxuNQAB0deLdZbbWE3Aq2Czw5z8qbs8N6hMtmLi5beHlnySEHFst3gVmKCheUX+HPnevvnL7mvTf+6l6MAAdSwPIQH0WAoDyBw722EBNguVoIAgTJMG9bBQJgapYFMGYwNsMC1R8JYMESGBDX-Og+05QhZxoyw2AAIho2d6IAH0Ymj6Po+U6AoOJ+EoGZgj4GAEFmBxoAqDBKjyKA724YFuAE6NY2hAikD3cokCgfRuDAGBOwQ1owFwNpi3eYIDN9JNI14wJMhgCcYAAfiIGBRRZXiLzQ4IJ1lWgJ3c2UYBaG0kHmTIfysaJ20Tf1aThJIPz9KEA0vYs0V5HA83uaUIEilUCwATRZFBAKYDwAAkYGERxHBQFMPCYCcADlqABOJYpS+L4VoJEyBRE1zkqMcyEtBo8Q0O0nkdGBAF4NwBZHZgZ1ogKjxitKgDyoqicAFUQxquqGqa1r2sOKy4p1BLKxgSj+j6o1aAkoaRvabFxrESb7W4F7NG0QazSsaZ6KoeiYBYmB6LG3EoC4ubAFw95bTpAJZ1KWEBKmLc6usu+EW3-QgBvotEWHo6YoetGApFkYkiRJaRySAA)

---

EDIT: If you specifically want to enforce that `keyMembers` has properties `hash` and `range`, you can modify `extractKeys()`:

```
function extractKeys<T extends object, K extends keyof T>(
    entity: T,
    keys: { hash: K, range: K }
) {
    const ret = {
        [keys.hash]: entity[keys.hash],
        [keys.range]: entity[keys.range]
    } as Pick<T, K>;
    return ret as any as (typeof ret extends infer O ? { [P in keyof O]: O[P] } : never);
}
```

[Updated Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBBIFsCmBRMUCWUCeMC8MA3gFAxkwYAmAXDAOTzICSldANKecAE5ICGUJJQCCUWgEYATAGYZAFknyArNI7kYYPslp0AIgFdKSBH0jh2xAL7EcAByQwAyolTos2ACrZ7+GHaQgAGZwLmiYOADcxMSgkLAA1kjYALLGAEZI3BC+JOoAFnwQeTpUFurcpgDmSDo8-IIiUBaWMIUwsdARMAD03TAAPAC0gxpIQn4FUGwwINwwAG58ADb6SNkA7hhLSzAAVvrQMBlwUNwYYJU23g4A0kmpCBlZXj4E-kEwiSnpmRBRMeBDutTFAUAAPU58YANXRpO64Ai5chUHSMJAsMpcXgCISiCQyeSKaRyFQcaxXHzgyHQoSw+EvBx4ThkAAKGGA8X6zmQYXcDOm8IeTwgDIA2gAiApFcUwAA+MHFFQuSHFAF0AHxRboAKj81xgVIqNModKSDJyzIoNBOZwuUXUdRxjVoYH0j0yUUs2u60UC+jA0Iw4BgSAhRqg8Ig-Q8IYhSDAlGyIDSuyQ0IFscECeyXw+HnVAApLfHwthaB41OQvhBaIQYFLijAbtMldVaDcYNYAJRES0dWC8WCIy3qUXVgB0DdVtBL7jHSQgk8KeVVlfUZHn2EXraQ05Dbhwm+3VV3lpabTZHOjAs1lt6MAA6lg8iB9LAoHkHIEQNsQJsLq0EAQJkmDBtgr4wNUsCmDMb62G+eo+EsGCJDAd59HQl6coQ464ZYbDirh47irKhG4eK4rqnQFBxPwlAzMEfAwAgswONAFQYJUeRQN+3DAtw9HJqm0KIUg46WoO+jcGAMCDoBrRgLgbQFu8wRyaGWaJjRgSZDAADyMAAPxEDAoosjRnxJB8el7npZmqp2MAukg8yZF2nrRP2mbhrScJJL4GnhpGBZoryODTF8Qq-O5xA6jAHgAJosigj5MB4AASMDCI4jgoAASh4TB6QActQAJxN5UIwn5Za9uoKI2uclT2li9S4mIGhuk8nowIAvBuALI7MDetEcWJclqUZXpACqMbZblBVFaV5WHIFVW+fCtBYf0SJkA17FNS1ZCOg0eKde63CHRoWg1I1dpWNM4pUDK8risd7WUX1gC4e8Ny0-mJSwgJUBarcaprYD296EA14poiw4rTG9zowFIsjEkSJLSOSQA)

Cheers!

Comment: Thanx for this! While I agree that `Record<string, keyof Entity>` makes absolute sense in the function, I'd appreciate it, if instead, you manage to use the `{ hash: keyof Entity, range?: keyof Entity }` type as it's one of the top level args that would be passed around the whole abstraction. I updated my attempt with `Pick` in the question.